# Create a websocket connection (WS and not WSS) over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

We want to create a web socket connection between 2 pages, one of them is deployed using cloudfront and the other has an auto signed SSL certificate.

When trying to create a socket connection to the second page we get this error :

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://x.x.x.x/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Any solution to make this happen ?

**Solved**

We solved this using a DNS server (AWS route53) that create a dns for the VM (*.example.com) and we put a SSL certificate (for the domain *.example.com) into that VM

Comment: You can't do that.  You should always use SSL.

Comment: The problem is that we are creating VMs in the fly, so we can't create certificate to every one of them.

Comment: You can set the browser to allow connections to that server (to that certificate) but that won't be a solution if you want to use something like this in production.